# When making a copy of list A by calling list(A), will Python pre-allocate the exact size of the list in advance?

Tags: python, list, dynamic-memory-allocation

It is my understanding that when appending hundreds of items to a list, eventually Python will create a brand new list with a larger buffer so that additional elements can continue to be added.

However, let's say I have a list as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = list(a)
```

Since Python technically knows how many elements b will hold, will it take the "smart" approach and allocate 5 spaces in advance?

Accordingly, would the above approach be more efficient in creating a deep copy compared to using a for loop? For example:

```
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i)
```

Comment: (1) How/if Python optimizes list creation is implementation dependent so you can only ask this for e. g. CPython, Pypy,... in particular. (2) Neither code snippet creates a deep copy, there is "copy.deepcopy" from the standard library for this. It wouldn't make sense for this example anyway.

Comment: Is the reason for (2) that the elements themselves would need to be reconstructed in a deep copy, which my code is not doing?

Comment: Right, deep copy means that all items in a container (like e. g. a list) are also cloned for the target container. If an item is itself a container, its items must be cloned as well and so on. Exception can be made for immutable objects like numbers. Therefore in your example a shallow copy has the same result as a deep copy.